# How to apply an extra class to a taxonomy ul?

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-taxonomy

In Drupal, I render a list of taxonomy-items in the node template, using

```
print render($content['field_my_taxonomy']);
```

It displays a list like:

```
<ul class="links">
  <li class="taxonomy-term-reference-0">
       <a property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" typeof="skos:Concept" href="somewhere">
         Tomaten
       </a>
   </li>
   (...)
```

So far, so good. Now, I'd like to apply some of my own classes to both the **li**-tags and to the **ul**-tag.

I've managed to add a class to each **li**-tag via **theme_preprocess_node**:

```
$vars['content']['field_my_taxonomy'][$i]['#options']['attributes']['class'] = "my-li-class";
```

*(where $i contains the index of the li-item).*

However, I cannot find a similar procedure to add a class to the **UL**

I have found soultions involving creating template-files for specific fields, or involving overriding the theme function for taxonomy items alltogether. I don't like these solutions, because the involve adding quite a bit of "bloat" to my theme. I'd like to just add a new item to an array and let Drupal take care of the rendering. Surely, it must be possible to add  **['attributes']['class']='my-ul-class** to an array somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the `theme_item_list($variables)` theme function **or** implement a hook_preprocess_HOOK function which would be `hook_preprocess_item_list($variables)` I think. The first would do your alterations in the theme itself, the second would do the alterations before going to the normal theme function.

links:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7

Comment: Thanks!

That would undoubtly work as well, but that would also require me to generate the list 'from skratch'. I'm looking for a 'clean' solution, where I only change the value of an array, and let Drupal take care of the rest. I'd simply like to keep the theme as clean as possible.

Comment: You just have to copy and paste the original theme function and add what you need. No need to do anything 'from scratch'.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your answer. It's just not as elegant as simply adding a class to array. I'll mark it as 'asnwered', although I believe the actual answer simply is ❝_no, it can't be done_❞.